# Install global typings from npm script

Tags: npm, typescript-typings

Installed typings globally

```
> npm install typings -g
```

Installed several typings

```
> typings install dt~angular --save --global
> typings install dt~angular-ui-router --save --global
> typings install dt~ui-grid --save --global
> typings install npm~lodash --save
```

All works fine, typings.json file is created together with typings folder. And when I run "typings install" from command line I get expected output

```
> typings install

├── lodash@4.0.0
├── angular (global)
├── angular-ui-router (global)
└── ui-grid (global)
```

Then I add npm script to automate a little bit project deployment

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "typings install"
},
```

But when I try to run "npm install" only module typings are installed. Global typings are completely ignored

```
> typings install


└── lodash@4.0.0
```

Tried to add --global flags into package.json but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have a LOCAL version of `typings` that is not 1.3.2

Run `npm install -D typings@latest`

Comment: Yep, you're right. For some reason it was v0.7.7 installed locally. Your solution helped. Thanks